# How to extract Subject-Verb-Object from a sentence?

Tags: computational-linguistics, syntax-trees, parts-of-speech, parsing

Given a corpus of sentences, is there a way to extract subject-verb-object triplets? What is the state-of-art in detecting SVO triplets?

Comment: did you get the solution for this?I am looking for the same type of code

Answer (score 1):

[Stanford OpenIE](https://github.com/philipperemy/Stanford-OpenIE-Python) performs best on my test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for a **parser**.

The most popular parser these days is probably **spaCy**.

It’s in Python and supports more languages than the library from Stanford.